# How do I get rid of irrelevant thinking?

Tags: practical-islam

I am Muslim. I want to be a good Muslim. I do pray salat. However, sometimes some irrelevant thoughts come on my head. How can I get rid of them?

Comment: You need to expand on your question, when does this thinking occur and what is it regards?

Answer (score 2):

Assalamualaikum brother,

Many of us are subject to this "irrelevant thinking" while offering our prayers . The root cause for this is the lack of concentration on what one is reciting and infinite thoughts of mundane matters . These are the tricks of Shaytaan to distract the believers from their prayers till the time they completely forget what they were reciting . The best remedy , according to me for this is to ponder over the meanings of the words that one is reading and think of the message that has been conveyed by Allah, may he be glorified and exalted. When you offer prayer , do it with complete devotion to God and I again repeat that do not fall into Shaytaan's trap by thinking of wordly stuff . Pray as if it is your last prayer. 
Hope this helps you brother :) .